# maven-surefire-plugin isn't working with profiles

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have profile configuration in my POM with surefire-maven-plugin & junit connection to run only specific tests by profile. For example:

```
mvn clean test -Pgroup1 --also-make -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

It works as expected with following versions:

```
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
```

But stops working normally when I try to upgrade them:

```
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
<junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
```

In this case `mvn test` always run all tests as I wouldn't set profile in command line.
My config of profiles is:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/unit/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>group1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/unit/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <groups>com.Group1</groups>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>group2</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/unit/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <groups>com.Group2</groups>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        ......................
    </profiles>
```

Every test class has connected interface linked to profile:

```
@Category(Group1.class)
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class Group1Test {
```

Playing with 'default' profile and 'activeByDefault' property also gave me no result. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @LucianoFiandesio hi. I've found in that project hidden dependencies related to junit5 and excluded them all (junit-jupiter, junit-vintage-engine, mockito-junit-jupiter) - it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by using "executions" in both the default plugin and in the profile plugin (which is not, by the way, an override of the default one)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
  ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals><goal>test</goal></goals> <!-- REQUIRED -->
            <configuration>
              <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <log4j.debug>true</log4j.debug>
                <client.test.url>http://localhost:8080/axis/services/MyService</client.test.url>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/TestAccountOp</exclude> <!-- Tomcat required - use the profile -->
                <exclude>**/TestWsdl</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>myprofileid-testwithtomcat</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
            <executions>
              <execution> <id>default-test</id> <phase>none</phase> </execution> <!-- Disable default Maven execution -->
              <execution>
                <id>myexecutionid-testwithtomcat</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals><goal>test</goal></goals> <!-- REQUIRED -->
                <configuration>
                  <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <log4j.debug>true</log4j.debug>
                    <client.test.url>http://localhost:8080/axis/services/MyService</client.test.url>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/TestWsdl</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
</project>
```

In the profile, I removed the "default-test", otherwise the "excludes" were set from the default one, but that might have been before I moved the "configurations" into the "executions". You have to remember that "default-test" is active unless you disable it, but not using an "execution" in the main body did not work for me.

"default-test" is Maven's "id" for the one in the main body, so that is why I used that name in the "execution" in the main body.

I think you can get away with not bothering with the "phase" elements, because that's the default for the "test" goal, but I'm pretty sure that you need the goal.

Good luck!